# docker rmi command cannot remove an exist image - No such image

Tags: docker

[image: docker rmi - No such image]
I tried to remove an image named node but failed. Other images could be removed correctly. But I don't know why this one cannot be deleted. any idea?
`[root@services merged]#docker --version Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88 [root@services merged]#docker images REPOSITORY                          TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE mysql                               latest      26d0ac143221   3 days ago     546MB gcr.io/flaaash/restful-test         latest      dcdc1ff5d02a   2 weeks ago    123MB ubuntu                              latest      4dd97cefde62   2 weeks ago    72.9MB node                                14-buster   692d89ab71cd   3 weeks ago    911MB portainer/portainer-ce              latest      96a1c6cc3d15   6 weeks ago    209MB gcr.io/distroless/nodejs-debian10   latest      15d9870f3275   51 years ago   121MB [root@services merged]#docker rmi 692d89ab71cd Error: No such image: 692d89ab71cd [root@services merged]#docker rmi node.14-buster Error: No such image: node.14-buster`

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Please don't post pictures of text; they are hard to read (or not readable at all) by some people and are useless for search engines. [Edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/640615/edit) and replace the picture with text.

Comment: A search for the error [image has dependent child images](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=docker+%22image+has+dependent+child+images%22&ia=web) yields several results. Have you researched them?

Comment: Regarding the "no such image" error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381888/docker-images-shows-image-docker-rmi-says-no-such-image-or-reference-doe.

Answer (score 0):

I could `cd /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256` and delete the tag, but I am afraid there are files still keep in the system.
Also, I don't want to `docker image prune -a` to clean all my unused images.
BTW, who can tell me how to know the folder contains the image layers and from this, we can delete relative files manually.